# PHP 7.2 throws run "composer require symfony/dotenv", 7.1 does not

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

A Symfony 4.2 application built (& working) in PHP 7.1, when switched to 7.2 throws

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Please run "composer require
>   symfony/dotenv" to load the ".env" files configuring the
>   application...

Further, `composer update` yields `Nothing to install or update` and then

> Script cache:clear returned with error code 255 !! !!  Fatal error:
>   Uncaught RuntimeException: You need to add "symfony/framework-bundle"
>   as a Composer dependency. in
>   G:\Documents\workspace\mana\bin\console:14

After updating composer.json to require PHP 7.2, it now includes:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.1",
    "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^2.0",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.6",
    "ob/highcharts-bundle": "^1.6",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "symfony/asset": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
    "symfony/form": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/templating": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/translation": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/validator": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.2.*"
},
```

Edit: If, as suggested in the error message, `composer update` is run, the following occurs. As can be seen in `composer.json` above, this is nonsensical.

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: You need to add
>   "symfony/framework-bundle" as a Composer dependency. in
>   G:\Documents\workspace\mana\bin\console:14

Edit #2:
This does not appear to be a Symfony or a PHP issue. I'm working in Windows and have a Hyper-V Ububtu 18 server running a clone of the app in Apache/2.4.29, PHP Version 7.2.19 without a problem. Makes it a whole lot harder to sort out. Place this Q on hold?

Edit #3:
Restored a two month old Windows image and got the same effect. Returned to current image and learned that the errors described above start somewhere between PHP 7.10 & 7.16 on this box. Upgrading Symfony to 4.3 does not help. ARRRGGGHHH!

Final edit:
Sorting this out is beyond my skill set. I'll end with the output of PHP 7.2.20. There is no dev.log created. Netbeans 11 does not seem to recognize xdebug. Here:

> (1/1) FatalErrorException
>
> Error: During class fetch: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class
>   PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase not found in
>   G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Test\KernelTestCase.php:24
>   Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\debug\DebugClassLoader.php(159):
>
> require('G:\Documents\wo...')
>
> ## 1 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\Bundle\...')
>
> ## 2 G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Test\WebTestCase.php(22):
>
> spl_autoload_call('Symfony\Bundle\...')
>
> ## 3 G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\debug\DebugClassLoader.php(159):
>
> require('G:\Documents\wo...')
>
> ## 4 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\Bundle\...')
>
> ## 5 G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\liip\functional-test-bundle\src\Test\WebTestCase.php(41):
>
> spl_autoload_call('Symfony\Bundle\...')
>
> ## 6 G:\Documents\workspace\mana\vendor\symfony\debug\DebugClassLoader.php(159):
>
> require('G:\Documents\wo...')
>
> ## 7 [internal function]: Sy in KernelTestCase.php line 24

Comment: that's a very nice diary entry. do you have a question though?

Comment: Sure. What does it take to make the app work in PHP 7.2? An implicit question now explicit.

Comment: Did you follow the suggestion from the first error message, and did you run `composer update` after the new composer.json? You don't really say. You might try reloading all with `rm -rf vendor` and then `composer update` again.

Comment: See edit above. Should have been included in original question.

Comment: Did you run the recommended command: `composer require symfony/dotenv`?

Comment: Running `composer require symfony/dotenv` just now, while updating a bunch of dependencies, ends up with `Uncaught ReflectionException: Class PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase not found`. No joy there.

Comment: All I can add is that one of the fixes noted in `news.txt` for PHP 7.2.19 is causing the failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got unstuck using the simplest possible solution - moving all the way up to PHP 7.3.7.

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered this issue, but in my case the issue is that composer had updated to 2.0.11 and that's what generated the error regarding that `Please run "composer require symfony/dotenv" to load the ".env" files configuring the application.`  I went back to composer 2.0.8 and all was well again.  I believe 2.0.9 also works.

Comment: Thank you! I ran into the same issue and can confirm that downgrading composer from 2.0.11 to 2.0.9 solved the issue.

Comment: I've had the same issue. I've just updated Symfony from 4.4.19 to 4.4.20 and it works.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem for almost three hours now. It turns out that I had to downgrade my flex version to 1.6 because higher versions of flex require dotenv version of at least 4.4.

I found that solution approach here: https://github.com/symfony/flex/pull/570

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly old, but I ran into this problem extensively recently and since I am not at all familiar with PHP it was driving me insane.  Just wanted to post this in case it could help anyone else.  It seems that the load path is simply messed up at times with regards to `symfony/dotenv`.  By running the following line, I was able to "live require" dotenv, even while the normal PHP loading mechanism would not quite do it:

```
sed '14irequire("/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php");' -i /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/flex/src/Command/DumpEnvCommand.php;
```

The leading `/var/www/html` would get replaced with whatever comes before your `vendor/` directory.  All that it does is insert a require statement to the file that does not seem to be correctly required by PHP.  After running this, I could run `composer dump-env prod` with no errors.

I wouldn't really call it the most elegant solution, but it did get the job done for me.